# Conversion of an Int to String value

Tags: java, string, int

If I want to convert a int to string and my code is

```
   database.setMinConnectionsPerPartition
   (dbPoolElement.getAttribute("ConPoolminConnections"));
```

Am I right in using (String.valueOf to convert it from int to string?

Comment: Solved :) Need to use integer.parsint

Comment: You need to provide code for me to comment :)

Comment: Thanks for offer of help!

Answer (score 2):

```
String.valueOf(number)

Integer.toString(number)
```

those are two I can think of now, that will return String value of int

Answer (score 0):

you could also do it implicitly

```
String s = myInt+"";
```